# Strange behavior in smooth pgfplot with sudden changes in the slope

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, algorithms, plot

I'm trying to plot some points with sudden changes in the slope. But I get some strange behavior like this:

[image]

as you can see in the peaks, there is no smoothness in there.

However, I think the problem is the interpolation algorithm, because tikz uses [bézier curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22601/what-is-the-smooth-plot-interpolation-algorithm-in-pgfplots). So I'm wondering is there a way to overcome this problem?

I'm putting here just a sample of the data. However, I have several plots with these discontinuities, and I would like to get an automatic way of fixing them. If you need I can show more points in which discontinuities occur.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotstableread{
0.0000  0.0000
0.1561  0.8615
0.1614  0.8643
0.1669  0.8670
0.3619  0.8670
0.3679  0.8781
0.3739  0.8809
0.3799  0.8809
0.3858  0.8837
0.3918  0.8975
1.0000  1.0000
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ylabel=label,
  no markers,
  smooth
]
\addplot table [x index=0, y index=1] \datatable;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It appears to me as if you have a lot of samples. If you can sample your underlying function so densely, you can probably use the default line style `sharp plot` instead of `smooth`. Your example immediately and automatically looks great if you uncomment `smooth`. Note that `smooth` should be considered as "draw something somehow nicely" rather than "interpolate strictly using high order interpolation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add and play with the `tension=0.08` option to the axis (the smaller the number, sharper it gets within the scale `[0,1]`.

But the main problem is you have groups of points too close to each other and suddenly jumps to a higher valued group which constrains the freedom of the turn and makes the interpolation ill-conditioned. I would suggest to leave out the too-close(!) points out, if possible.