# Ugly two ordinates plot

Tags: pgfplots

For some reason the plot generated from this code looks extremely ugly. The two series look like they were hand-painted. I thought the `smooth` property would help but still the same ugly plot.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-0.015:1.15,
    width=10cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.015,
    xmax=1.15,
    height=8cm,
    axis y line=left,
    xlabel=$x_{\alpha}$,
    ylabel=$y_{j}$]
    \addplot [id=logit,color=blue,thick,smooth,mark=x] coordinates   {(-0.0148,-1.56862) (0.02902,-3.28582)(0.06382,-3.28582)(0.12780,-2.56495)(1.13767,-3.33220)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[domain=-0.015:1.15,
    width=10cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.015,
    xmax=1.15,
    height=8cm,
    axis y line=right,
    axis x line=none,
    ylabel=$\tau_{j}$]
    \addplot [id=txdef,color=green,thick,smooth,mark=*] coordinates   {(-0.0148,0.17241) (0.02902,0.03571)(0.06382,0.03571)(0.12780,0.07143)(1.13767,0.03448)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: I added an image of the result to your question and the plot looks ok to me. If you get another result you may ry to update your distribution. If the image looks like mine but it shouldn’t please explain in more detail, whats wrong with it …

Comment: And whats the problem with it? I can’t see anything _ugly_ or _hand-drawn_ …

Comment: Tobi the is extra curvature with the plot that is not supposed to be there. Just look at the first 3 points.

Comment: `smooth` creates that curvature.

Comment: And removing it doesn't help either. I have a similar plot in Excel and it's nowhere similar to the plot above.

Comment: Without `smooth` you'll get straight lines between points, does that not happen for you?

Comment: See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22601/what-smooth-plot-interpolation-algorithm-does-pgfplots-use): pgfplots uses cubic bezier splines to make smooth lines.  If you want a "nicer" plot give it more data points.

Comment: You can also change the 'amount' of curving by adjusting the `tension`. For example, try `smooth,tension=0.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what the plot looks like when I remove the two `smooth` keys. Is this what you're trying to achieve? If not, what do you want the plot to look like?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-0.015:1.15,
    width=8cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.015,
    xmax=1.15,
    height=8cm,
    axis y line=left,
    xlabel=$x_{\alpha}$,
    ylabel=$y_{j}$]
    \addplot [id=logit,color=blue,thick,mark=x] coordinates   {(-0.0148,-1.56862) (0.02902,-3.28582)(0.06382,-3.28582)(0.12780,-2.56495)(1.13767,-3.33220)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[domain=-0.015:1.15,
    width=8cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.015,
    xmax=1.15,
    height=8cm,
    axis y line=right,
    axis x line=none,
    ylabel=$\tau_{j}$]
    \addplot [id=txdef,color=green,thick,mark=*] coordinates   {(-0.0148,0.17241) (0.02902,0.03571)(0.06382,0.03571)(0.12780,0.07143)(1.13767,0.03448)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Removing 'smooth' and adjusting the width helped improve the looking of the plot. Thanks

Comment: @Jake why is this CW?