# How does TikZ/pgf resp. pgfplots do data smoothing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, plot

I am plotting smoothed data curves by applying the `smooth` option to the according diagram curve like this:

```
\addplot[color=black, mark=none, smooth] table[x=time, y=measured, col sep=semicolon] {./data.csv};
```

I was using those plots internally only. However, since those should be used for a scientific publication in the future I need some information about the smoothing polynomial in order to back the plotting up a bit.

I had a look into both the pgfplots manual and the pgf/TikZ manual which do not seem to provide any further information about the used smoothing polynomial or algorithm.

So does anyone know which approach/algorithm is used to smooth the data before plotting?

Comment: (Is it possible to access source code and look yourself?)

Comment: See [What “smooth” plot interpolation algorithm does pgfplots use?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22601/what-smooth-plot-interpolation-algorithm-does-pgfplots-use). I would not recommend using this for a scientific publication. In that case, you should fit an explicit function, like shown in [pgfplots/gnuplot: How to find the curve-fitting function passing through certain points and plot it?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340861/2552) or [Smooth curve through points with pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109457/2552)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smoothing is not done globally hence there is no actual smoothing polynomial is used. Instead of connecting the consecutive points with line segments, a bezier curve is used to connect consecutive points in the parsed input stream with approx equal in out angles defined by the control points of the Bezier curves. Hence if there is a steep change between points you should expect overshoots/undershoots. This is also mentioned in the manual under `smooth` key.

You can see the actual code in `pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex` file line 24. The `\pgfplothandlercurveto` macro definition is the actual algortihm.

In scientific publications, you should not alter the data with smooth keys for aesthetic reasons, or smoothen for a purpose with the provided actual code how it is done.

Comment: Thanks for the information, that explains a lot of anomalous behavior.  There are better ways of smoothing than bezier curves.  Hmmm.

Comment: @JPi: It's worth keeping in mind that the `smooth` key is a TikZ key, not a PGFPlots key: this function was originally intended for drawing, not for smoothing data plots.

Comment: @Jake It was intended for plots though hence the plot handler. Only in the regular paths there are very few points.

Comment: How hard would it be to add one's own smoothing algorithm?

Comment: @JPi Current one is also a smoothing algorithm. Depends on the complexity.

Comment: @percusse: Yes, it is, but not a good one.  I can compute the numbers easily in Lua......