# How does the `smooth` option in `draw' works

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-graphdrawing, smooth

While drawing a curve in `tikz`, the `smooth` option in `draw` command makes the output much desired, smooth, and nice to eyes. I want to know how does it do that. To get the same output without the `smooth` option, one must increase the number of intermediate nodes, resulting in much higher compilation time. For example, the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [smooth, samples=10, domain=-1:1] plot (\x,{\x*\x*\x});
        \draw [samples=1000, domain=-1:1] plot (\x,{\x*\x*\x-0.1});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces almost same figures. One needs to really zoom in and nitpick to find the difference. I wonder how does `smooth` complete this job without taking more compilation time.

Comment: I *think* smooth is doing cubic splines, so it would not be a surprise that works OK on up-to-order 3 polynomials. Have you tried with trigonometric or exponential functions?

Comment: Perhaps see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354755/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22601/  Also, not what you're asking about, but here is one example where `smooth` doesn't really work well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371245/how-to-create-a-ricker-wavelet-in-tikz/371248#371248